# S3::getObjectInfo [403] Unexpected HTTP status

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using the `getObjectInfo($bucket, $fileUri)` to get the details of the files I have on S3.

The same code is working on an EC2 instance & I'm getting the below response:

```
object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["body"]=>
  NULL
  ["headers"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["date"]=>
    int(1447937934)
    ["time"]=>
    int(1447835426)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "9841b46a11dfe58z86196cfr812i81sv"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["size"]=>
    int(5415)
  }
  ["code"]=>
  int(200)
}
```

But when I'm trying the same code from a local machine, I'm getting the below response :

```
object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["body"]=>
  NULL
  ["headers"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/xml"
    ["date"]=>
    int(1447935810)
  }
  ["code"]=>
  int(403)
}
```

And this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  S3::getObjectInfo(bucket01,folder1/2015_01_01/abcdefgh/abcdefgh.txt): [403] Unexpected HTTP status in /abc/def/S3.php on line 355
```

I'm using amazon S3 PHP class for REST from below link : http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

I feel there is an issue with S3 Bucket policy but not sure what.
Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the issue was AWS CLI version mismatch in Local machines.

Installed the latest version of AWS CLI in all local machines and it resolved the issue.

Now I'm getting 200 (OK) status for all my requests.